# Inventory Management System in 3 Hours?

Tags: database, database-design, inventory, purchase-order

**Inventory Requisition Process:**
Whenever a user requires inventory, user generates an inventory requisition, and if the inventory is available, the inventory will be directly issued and user’s inventory account will be updated. In case the inventory is not available, the purchase order will be generated for the required inventory to the corresponding vendor and sent to the vendor. Once the purchase order is received back, it will be updated as per the received inventory items. Finally the payment of the purchase order will be made. Hence the inventory will be updated accordingly. Once the inventory becomes available, based on inventory requisition, it will be issued to the end user, and the user’s inventory account will be updated.

---

**Test Requirement:** 
On the basis of Inventory Management System, business process, and system design provided to you, you are required to develop “Inventory Management” and “Purchase Order Management” modules. You can use language of your choice for developing the given system.

**Inventory Management Module:**
Inventory Management Module handles the inventory requisition, inventory issuance, and inventory stocks maintenance.

**Purchase Order Management Module:**
Purchase Order Management Module handles the purchase order generation and purchase order receiving.

---

**My Question**
What will be strategy you use to develop this type of application in 3 Hours to achieve target.

1. **Application Type**

   Asp.net Application or Winform Application
2. **Architecture**

   Should we make proper classes for all entity and then work on it? and stored procedures. Or just working on controls value and pass run time SQL quires?
3. **Database Design**

   What would be the ERD of this Application?
4. **Reference Material**

   Please give reference of materials where i can demo online these modules?

Comment: umm. sounds like a "send me the codez" question... :)

Comment: Now you are down to 2 hours and 50 minutes.

Comment: though it is an old question but an answer could be to use SAP if i am correct

Answer (score 9):

The strategy to achieve this in three hours is to call the client and tell them that unfortunately, the next three hour opening on your calendar is in four weeks. Also, the hourly rate for those three hours will be $2500.

Answer (score 0):

asp.net

run time sql

ERD? you should hire some one if you very thing ready made

refernce- the internet

in 3 hours not possible unless you are an expert, that would mean you would not ask this question so not possible

Comment: One of the most astute answers I've read in a long time.  :-)